# Doctrine 2: Query result as associative array

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm, dql

In my Repository class I use the following code to query:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery("
    SELECT s.term, COUNT(s.term) AS freq
    FROM App\Entities\SearchTerm s
    GROUP BY s.term
    ORDER BY s.term ASC
");

$result = $query->getResult();
```

The result I get is something like:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'term' => string '' (length=0)
      'freq' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'term' => string 'foo' (length=3)
      'freq' => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'term' => string 'bar' (length=3)
      'freq' => string '2' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'term' => string 'baz' (length=3)
      'freq' => string '2' (length=1)
```

But I would rather have an associative array as a result:

```
array (size=4)
  '' => string '1' (length=1)
  'foo' => string '1' (length=1)
  'bar' => string '2' (length=1)
  'baz' => string '2' (length=1)
```

Is this possible **without an extra for-loop** to build the desired array?

Comment: This trait give the result in expected format https://gist.github.com/ajaxray/9ef4c5dcc4e2aa881240370b6f27c8f4

Answer (score 23):

I know its old but today I had to do almost the same, my solution without a custom hydrator

- INDEX BY s.term
- modify the getResult() to be sure

like

```
$result = $query->getQuery()->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

- format the result

as

```
$resultNeeded = array_map(function($value) { return $value['freq']; }, $result);
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want an array you can use [the `getArrayResult` method](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php#L674-L684).

> Gets the array of results for the query.
>
> Alias for execute(null, HYDRATE_ARRAY).

```
$result = $query->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

So using this method will give you [the exact same result as using the constant `HYDRATE_ARRAY`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php#L692).

Comment: Prove me i am wrong, but i think it wont return the desired associative array. 
I tried it and it will return each result-line as an own array element which holds inside the associative array.

Answer (score 5):

Use **INDEX BY** :

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT c FROM SomeBundle:Configuration c INDEX BY c.name');
$query->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

I saw it here and it works fine : https://coderwall.com/p/crz4dq/defining-a-column-to-be-the-key-of-the-result-hydrated-as-array-in-doctrine-2

Answer (score 2):

Actually *somewhere* the transposition has to be done. See [*Hydration Modes*](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#hydration-modes) about what is returned by `->getResult()` and which alternatives modes/variants already exist.

You can also add your own hydration mode at a central place. That is explained in [*Custom Hydration Modes*](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#custom-hydration-modes).

Answer (score 1):

After lot of search I have found some solutions for **doctrine object to array conversion**. When we have associated objects in result.

**1.**

```
$person = $em->find('Person', 2);
$da = array();
        $person = (array) $person;
        foreach($person as $i=>$d) {
            if (is_object($d)) {
                $d = (array) $d;
                foreach($d as $si=>$sd){
                    if (is_object($sd)) {
                        //var_dump('after convert array');
                        $da[$i][$si] = (array) $sd ;
                         //var_dump($da[$i][$si]);
                    } else {
                       $da[$i][$si] = $sd ;
                       //var_dump($da[$i][$si] );
                    }
                }

            } else {
                $da[$i] = $d;
                //var_dump($da[$i]);
            }
        }

echo '<pre>'; print_r($da); echo '<pre>'; exit;
```

**2.**

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT w FROM  Person w WHERE w.Id = 2');
$person = $query->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
echo '<pre>';  \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($person); exit;
```

**3.**

```
 $result = $em->createQueryBuilder();
            $person = $result->select('p')
            ->from('PsnPersonPsn', 'p')
            ->where('p.Id= 1')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
             echo '<pre>';  \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($person); exit;
```