# How do I return an associative array from two fields in a doctrine query?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

My database table looks like this;

```
id   name
---------
1    Open
2    On Hold
3    Closed
```

the result i want is an associative array like this;

array(1 => 'Open', 2 => 'On hold', 3 => 'Closed');

I can't find any simple way to return these results from doctine, so I'm using this code;

```
$query = $this->em->createQuery("SELECT s FROM Project\Entity\ProjectStatus s");
$statuses = $query->getResult();
$result = array();
foreach($statuses as $status)
{
    $result[$status->getId()] = $status->getName();
}
return $result;
```

This feels long winded. Is there a simpler way?
I've tried Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY but it still includes the field names in the resulting array. I just wan't the values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine 2: Query result as associative array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002888/doctrine-2-query-result-as-associative-array)

Comment: Any success with my answer? Or is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered **[before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657835/how-to-get-a-one-dimensional-scalar-array-as-a-doctrine-dql-query-result)**
As of PHP 5.5 you can use `array_column` to solve this

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
    ->select('s.name');
$query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
```

or

```
$query = $this->em->createQuery("SELECT s.name FROM Project\Entity\ProjectStatus s");
```

and then

```
$result = $query->getArrayResult();
$names = array_column($result, 'name');
```

Use `s.name`, there is no need to get the whole `ProjectStatus` if you only need the name.